# can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

Tags: python

Tengo un arreglo del cual extraigo un dato para pasarlo a un **insert**, el me corre el código, hasta que se encuentra con un dato vacío. Antes le hago una validación, pero siento que no la toma. Hasta donde tengo entendido, diferente es con `!=`, en ese orden pregunto si el dato es diferente de nulo realizar el **insert**, sino no hacer nada; pero me da el siguiente error:

```
Insertando xxxxxxxxxx
Insertando xxxxxxxxxx
Insertando xxxxxxxxxx
Insertando xxxxxxxxxx
can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

Este es mi código:

```
def Consultas():
    from con_Bases import BDSu as Su, BDM as Mc
    try:
        with open("D./UnicaSU.sql",'r') as query:
            data = query.read()
            cursor = Su().cursor()
            cursor.execute(data)
            cursor.close            
            Su().commit()
            Su().close            
            exportD = cursor.fetchall()
            
            print("antes")
            print("tabla limpia")
            cursor = Mc().cursor()
            
            for row in exportD:
                x = row[33]
                if x != "":
                    print("Insertando "+x)                    
                    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TEMP (CAMPO) values("+x+")")                
                    Mc().commit()
            print("Insert ejecutado")    
            cursor.close
            Mc().close()
```

Answer (score 0):

`None` no es lo mismo que una cadena vacía `""`:

```
> None == "" 
False
```

Sin embargo tanto `None`, como `""` son evaluadas como un booleano `False`, por lo que se puede usar directamente: `if x:`. Ver [objetos evaluados como True y False](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).
Entonces después del `for` el código quedaría:

```
            # ...
            x = row[33]
            if x:
                # ...
```

EDIT: Un `0` entero puede ser evaluado como `False`, y a lo mejor es necesario ser insertado, entonces en ese caso, una solución puede ser:

```
            # ...
            x = row[33]
            if x not in [None, '']:
                # ...
```